# Binding a Silverlight TabControl to a complex object using a converter

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, binding, tabcontrol

I am trying to bind my data to a tab control. I have got the headers displaying fine but I'm not sure how I get the content of the tabs to bind correctly based on my item template shown below.

I think I'm missing something when I'm creating the tab item but I'm not sure how to bind my MyCustomObject to each of the TabItem's.

XAML:

```
<sdk:TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Singles,Converter={StaticResource TabConverter}}">
            <sdk:TabControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </sdk:TabControl.ItemsPanel>
            <sdk:TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource RoundNumberConverter}}" Margin="2" />
                        <ListBox x:Name="Matches" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="2">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition />
                                            <RowDefinition />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SeedingConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}" Margin="2" />
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SeedingConverter}, ConverterParameter=false}" Margin="2" />
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Player1Name}" Margin="2" />
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Player2Name}" Margin="2" />

                                    </Grid>


                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </sdk:TabControl>
```

Converter:

```
 public class TabConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyCustomObject>> source = value as IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyCustomObject>>;
            if (source != null)
            {
                var controlTemplate = (ControlTemplate)parameter;

                List<TabItem> result = new List<TabItem>();
                foreach (IGrouping<string, MyCustomObject> tab in source)
                {
                    result.Add(new TabItem()
                    {
                        Header = tab.Key,
                        DataContext = tab //not sure this is right?
                    });
                }
                return result;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're most of the way there, the following works for me:

Strip out your DataTemplate and drop its contents straight into a new UserControl, for the example here, lets call it MatchesView.

Then in your TabConverter, amend the contents of the foreach loop to something like the following:

```
TabItem tabitem = new TabItem();
tabitem.Header = tab.Key;

MatchesView tabview = new MatchesView();
tabview.DataContext = parameter;

tabitem.Content = tabview;
result.Add(tabitem);
```

Note: this requires that you pass your ViewModel to the TabConverter as a parameter, eg:

```
<sdk:TabControl SelectedItem="{Binding YourSelectedObject}" ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollectionObject, Converter={StaticResource TabConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource YourViewModel}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Then, as you have your ViewModel in each instance of the new control, adjust your binding accordingly!

Note that the trick is that you have a separate binding for the single instance of  the Selected object

Answer (score 0):

checking your problem I think there is no support for that. The WPF's TabItem contains ItemTemplate & ContentTemplate. The first is the template for the **Header**, the second is the template for the "body". In silverlight we still have no ContentTemplate. Haven't seen an official statement yet, but [this guy](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/silverlight-tabcontrol-with-data-binding/) says it won't be supported till SL5.